# From the set $\mathbb{Z}_8=\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ select all elements for which there exists an inverse element with respect to multiplication

Tags: group-theory

I have a misunderstanding with what it means
**select all elements for which there exists an inverse element with respect to multiplication**
does it mean that an element from $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and for example $4\times2=8$ therefore it's the identity element? but doesn't that also apply for $4\times0$ for exapmle? or do i have to consider the elements $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ as just numbers and $a^{-1}=\frac{1}{a}$?

so to be more precise i have difficulties understanding the set of elements that has an inverse element with respect to multiplication from the set $\mathbb{Z}/8$

I would appriciate any help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the identity for addition, $0$, and the identity for multiplication, $1$.

Any numbers, that multiplied together, give the identity for ADDITION are called "zero divisors", and are precisely the non-invertible elements of your ring/algebra. For example this is the set of $0$-determinant matrices in a ring/algebra of square matrices; or the divisors of 8 (2, and 4)  in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$. This is the reason why only $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ where $p$ is prime are fields, since only in these do you have the fact that you have no non-unit divisors of $p$ (no zero divisors, and thus all elements are invertible).

Comment: So just to check if i understand, all divisors of $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are the zero divisors, because they give the identity element for addition, in my case 2 and 4, and all others would have an inverser and i'm thinking the inverse are themselves, like for example 3 where $3\times 3 =9$ and $9 mod 8=1$. But what would happen to 0 or 6? because we can't divide by 0 but any number multiplied by 0 would give back 0 and $6 mod 8 $ gives 4 which is not the identity.
Thanks for the response!

Comment: So: indeed, some elements can be their self-inverse. For example, the $1$ and $-1$ are always self-inverses for multiplication, but so is a matrix like $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \ 1 \\ 1 \ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. As for 6, I indeed forgot $6*4=24 \equiv 0 [8]$ which means 6 is also a zero divisor in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$. Zero is never invertible, but that's not a problem: that's expected.

Answer (score 1):

You want to determine the elements $x$ for which $\gcd(x,8)=1.$ For such $x$ there are integers $a,b$ for which $ax+8b=1,$ so that $a$ is an inverse for $x$ mod $8.$ More precisely, the element in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ which is congruent to $a$ mod $8$ is the inverse you want.